# how to run a c program using multiple cores (i7 machine) in shell scripting

Tags: c, shell, parallel-processing

I have a C program fextract which takes a wavfile as input and gives output in some fcc format.the syntax goes like this 'fextract file.wav file.fcc'. Now I have 75000 wav files which needs to be converted into fcc format. to speed up the procedure I am planing to use all the cores of my i7 machine. First I have saved all the input and output paths in a file which i call it as scp file
eg: /mnt/disk1/file1.wav /mnt/disk2/file1.fcc
    /mnt/disk1/file2.wav /mnt/disk2/file2.fcc
and so on

now using the following shell scripting i have devided the scp files into 8 files and stored in a temp directory

```
mkdir $tmpDir
cd $tmpDir

nCores=`cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep processor | wc -l`
nLines=`cat $scpFile|wc -l`

split -l $((nLines/nCores + 1)) $scpFile
```

now my temp file has eight subfiles. How can i assess them to run the program fextract using multiple cores

```
for i in `ls`
do 

fextract &i

done
```

need something of these kind. Please help me solve this its urgent

Answer (score 2):

Use GNU Parallel:

```
parallel -j $nCores fextract -- `ls`
```

Or you could use `xargs` with -P key (useful with `find`).

Those commands will launch your code in multiple threads, which will allow them to be executed on multiple cores.

Comment: Tip: On Ubuntu, you will need to `sudo apt-get install moreutils` in order to use this program.

Comment: could you be more specific please because my ls will give me 8 files and in each line in the files contains the input and output paths. so how can i implement that using the parallel command

Comment: -j $nCores is default for GNU Parallel. Tip: moreutils does _NOT_ contain GNU Parallel, but another program. See: http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/history.html

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel:

```
cat filenames | parallel fextract {} {.}.fcc
```

As some time is spent for disk I/O it may be faster to run a little more than 1 per cpu core:

```
cat filenames | parallel -j150% {} {.}.fcc
```

If you just want all files in current dir:

```
parallel -j150% {} {.}.fcc ::: *.wav
```

If you want to give both input and output filename on a single line separated by space you can use:

```
cat filenames_2_per_line | parallel --colsep ' ' -j150% {1} {2}
```

If the filenames are not on the same line but after each other, then you need to read 2 lines at a time:

```
cat filenames_interleaved | parallel -N2 -j150% {1} {2}
```

Watch the intro videos to learn more: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1